# Setting SelectedValue of a DropDownList on PageLoad

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a bit of a problem with a DropDownList I am using. When the user changes the SelectedIndex, they get redirected to the same page, but with a query string on the end based on their selected value.

Because I'm not posting, and redirecting instead, the state of the dropdownbox is not saved, so it always defaults to the first one.

But, if I save it in say a session, or set the selectedvalue according to the query string in Page_Load, when the user selects another listitem, the selection they have chosen is overridden by the selection delcared in Page_Load.

Any ideas on how to resolve this guys? Thanks

Comment: First idea: why do you redirect to the same page instead of let the DropDown-SelectedIndexChanged Event happen?

Comment: Because when they change the selection, it needs to set a query string

Comment: that's weird requirement.. but guess the boss/client can't change their minds. Anyway, "set the selectedvalue according to the query string in Page_Load" should work just fine, please post your code and we'll see what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your specific case you can try this:

include a **query string param** in your redirection query string. which indicate that user has selected a value.

in your **page_load** method check that **query string param** has that **value** , and set again for that drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

Why are u redirecting it? page redirect can not retrieve the viewstate value (they are vanished when u do)
instead set autopostback property of DropDownList to true
and then use the DropDownList.SelectedValue or Text property on the DropDownList event

you can also set the value in the Onprerender event of the page if you need to do it with a query string

Answer (score 0):

do not need to redirect just set `dropDownList1.AutoPostBack=True;`
**or**
set **AutoPostBack to True** from properties Window